# ACS with custom home realm discovery page, how do I "detect" Azure AD vs Microsoft Account?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-acs, liveid

I'm customizing an [ACS home realm discovery page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185963.aspx) and want to accommodate users who have either a "microsoft account" (aka LiveID/Passport) or a Office365/Azure Active Directory account.

In this situation, it's possible for the following workflow to happen (as far as I understand it)

1. User logs in using ACS custom page
2. User selects "Microsoft Account"
3. User types in their company / corporate ID
4. The HRD process at http://portal.microsoftonline.com redirects them to their ADFS server
5. Their ADFS server redirects them to their company.

Once sign-in passes (or fails) the login would cascade back to the ACS page.

What is the most efficient way (for the end user) to integrate Azure ACS, with Azure Active Directory / Office 365, with a custom HRD page that I create?

Or more plainly, is there a JSON web service that I can query to determine if a given domain or account exists within the "Microsoft Account/LiveID" world, and also check AzureAD for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot treat "microsoft accounts" (Windows Live ID / Outlook.com / hotmail / xbox /etc) the same as WAAD accounts when using ACS. When you set up your identity providers in ACS you will need to enable a Windows Live IDP and one IDP for each WAAD instance you are going to allow users to authenticate with. One thing that is not clear to me from your question is if you are needing for you users to be able to authenticate against a single WAAD tenant or from multiple. If one then you only need to configure one WAAD tenant in ACS. If you need to allow users to authenticate against multiple WAAD tenants then you will need to set up and IDP for each in ACS. For example if your web app is a SAAS application with users from companies "Contoso" and "Northwind" and you want them to be able to authenticate against their company's on-premise active directory then you will need two WAAD tenants setup. Each WAAD tenant will need to have federation configured with their given on-premise active directory. Each WAAD tenant in turn would need to be configured in ACS as an IDP. You could name those IDPs distinctly in ACS something like "Contoso WAAD" and "Northwind WAAD". Then in your custom implementation of the HRD page you can either just list all the IDPs and let the user choose, or if you want to be fancier you could parse the JSON results from the ACS endpoint that lists IDP and present them to the user (or just redirect them) based on some other selection they had made.